# ¿Como cambiar de tema en tema en windows form?

Tags: windows-forms

Tengo entendido como agregar temas a mi proyecto, me creo una clase "Theme" , le meto todo el código de un tema descargado y le cambio el espacio de nombre(namespace) para poder utilizar sus objetos.

Estas son las propiedades que me da el tema que yo fácilmente puedo arrastrar uno hasta el proyecto y cambiar todo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es cambiar de tema a tema a codigo con un combobox:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como podría hacer eso? :/

Answer (score 0):

Lo que ha descargado es una librería de controles, la única forma de cambiar el tema de su aplicación dinamicamente es que el desarrollador de esa librería haya programado la opción del cambio de tema, yo le puedo sugerir utilizar otras librerias/frameworks que si posee esa caracteristica:

[MaterialSkin for .NET WinForms](https://github.com/IgnaceMaes/MaterialSkin)

[MetroFramework - WinForms on steroids](https://github.com/dennismagno/metroframework-modern-ui)